# how to use php in front-end and java in back-end for a web- project

Tags: java, php, hadoop

have plan for using java in backend for a php project for connecting hadoop because hadoop is not supported by php but is supported by java , python etc. So I want to know is there way that I can do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To serve your purpose, you need to create webservices in java, for that purpose jersey Restful webservice will serve your need. There are some nice article on the web as follows:
[1. REST with Java (JAX-RS) using Jersey - Tutorial.](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html)
[2. Build a RESTful Web service using Jersey and Apache Tomcat](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-tomcat/)
(you will need to have Apache Tomcat to run java web project and Apache httpd server for php).
After creating it, your web services will be exposed to call from any front need (in your case php) provided if you give proper **consume** and **produce** mime type.

Comment: u sure that there is no bond required between java and php to work for a web-app and simply work with restful service... 

and if it is possible with restful service then wouldn't it make slow the connection between front-end and back-end

Comment: @NimmyJustin Yes I am sure, because even I worked for building restful api in java, which are being used from php, android etc.